# Risk of having keystore password and alias password different

Tags: java, keystore, password-protection, jks

I'm working on a java application that uses JKS keystores for mutual authentication. One thing I noticed is a bug where our keystore password and alias password have to be the same for one of our applications to work.

Besides not having unique passwords is typically bad practice, I was wondering if there were any studies or way to quantify the risk of not making nested keystore passwords and aliases different?

Answer (score 1):

Using a separate key-alias password in JSSE makes certain things impossible. For example there is no system property for it, so if you're relying on system properties to configure JSSE you have to not use key-alias passwords at all.